# XeLaTeX/xdvipdfmx or the driver bug with eps images

Tags: graphics, xetex, eps

It seems that xelatex has problems including eps images; please see the below example; eps image can be download from [LaTeX Graphics companion examples](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/examples/lgc2/w.eps) on CTAN.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics{w.eps}}
\end{document}
```

**latex+dvips+pstopdf:** image is included inside the `\fbox`

**xelatex recent versions:** image is outside of `\fbox`

**xelatex old versions: (the one coded by Jonathan Kew):** ok, image is included inside \fbox.

`w.eps` is taken from LaTeX graphics companion examples; therefore I do not think there is anything wrong with the image itself.

What is wrong?

Comment: I think your MWE does not compile with `xetex` since you provided a `\documentclass` command, but I can confirm the phenomenon you described with `xelatex`

Comment: I never meant plain in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps you should nevertheless clearify ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer From the earliest days of the site, we've been clear that LaTeX is assumed unless otherwise noted: realism!

Comment: When you say 'old version', could you be a bit more specific? A quick test suggests `dvipdfmx` does the same as `xdvipdfmx` here, so I suspect it's been around since before `xdvipdfmx` was written.

Comment: @JosephWright: By old version of XeTeX, I mean the one developed alone by Jonathan Kew and not Khaled Hosny. From the moment, Khaled Hosny was in charge of XeTeX, the behavior changed.

Comment: @VafaKaren-Pahlav Could you give us _e.g._ version numbers on this? My feeling from testing `dvipdfmx` is that the behaviour in `xdvipdfmx` is a simple copy of the same code. I don't think Khaled has altered the driver, so I'm wondering if for example you were using the `xdv2pdf` driver (Mac only)?

Comment: @JosephWright: Let's say xelatex binary included in TeXLive 2011 (whatever that version is).

Comment: @VafaKaren-Pahlav I'm not 100% sure this will work, but it might be instructive. Could you your test using `xelatex -no-pdf` and the 'old' version of XeTeX, then use `xdvipdfmx` on the `.xdv` file to convert to a PDF? If the problem is `xdvipdfmx` (my guess) then you should get the 'new' behaviour despite using the 'old' XeTeX.

Comment: I think between egreg and I we've tracked down the issue: a change in the `(x)dvipdfmx` drivers: http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=30175. Once I understand the issue properly I'll try to work out a fix!

Comment: @JosephWright: Great. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image `w.eps` is *not* an `eps` file, it is a `ps` file. This is the reason why it has not the correct bounding box values. Instead of

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%BoundingBox:100 100 150 150
100 100     translate % put origin at 100 100
...
```

it should be

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%BoundingBox:0 0 50 50
%100 100     translate % put origin at 100 100
...
```

Then it will be correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
X\fbox{\includegraphics{w1.eps}}X
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the `xdvipdfmx` driver should behave like the `dvips` driver, which ignores the `translate` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer. However the edited eps image per your suggestion is broken with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` (it is outside of `\fbox`)

Comment: The only difference I get is the fact that `pdflatex` and `lualatex` have paper format `letter`, whereas  `xelatex` and `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` have `a4`. However, all engines produce the above output.